# ¿Cómo unir 2 rows en un while?

Tags: php, sql, while

```
 while ($row2 =mysqli_fetch_array($results2)   ) 
    {

    echo "['".$row2["id_usuario"]."', ".$row2["number2"]."],    ";

    }
```

Quiero unir este row con un row3 que me traera otros datos de otra tabla ...

lo que quiero hacer es algo como

```
 while ($row2 =mysqli_fetch_array($results2) and ($row3 =mysqli_fetch_array($results3)   ) 
    {

    echo "['".$row2["id_usuario"]."', ".$row2["number2"]."],  ".$row3["color3"]."],   ";

    }
```

pero tengo errores

Comment: Que error te marca.

Comment: ¿Podrías colgar todo el código de la consulta?. Creo que el problema viene de la consulta y no de la forma de unir las filas.

Comment: Muy raro lo que quieres hacer. Pregunto: ¿por qué tienes dos consultas y no una? Si los quieres unir parece que las tablas se relacionan ya de por sí, ¿por qué no aprovechas las ventajas que ofrecen las bases de datos relacionales?

Answer (score 0):

los puedes ir almacenando en un arreglo dentro de tu while

ejemplo:

```
 $rowunion=array();
        while (($row2 =mysqli_fetch_array($results2)) and ($row3 =mysqli_fetch_array($results3)   ) 
            {
             $rowunion[]=array("id_usuario"=>$row2["id_usuario"],"number2"=>$row2["number2"],"color3"=>$row3["color3"]);
            }
    print_r($rowunion);
```